# Можно ли установить тегу img атрибут src в коде компонента в Angular 2?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Можно ли установить тегу img атрибут scr из кода компонента ?

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-local-url-stream',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard-local-url-stream.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dashboard-local-url-stream.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardLocalUrlStreamComponent extends Translation {
    _camera: Camera;
    streamLoading: boolean = true;
    errorContainerActive: boolean = false;
    localUrl: string;

    @Input() set camera(camera: Camera) {
        this.streamLoading = true;
        this.dashboardService.localUrlStreamConnected.next(false);
        this._camera = camera;
        this.localUrl = this.sanitize(this.dashboardService.localService.getLocalUrlStreamLink(camera));
        this.dashboardService.localService.checkLocalService()
            .then(() => {
                if (this.errorContainerActive) {
                    this.errorContainerActive = !this.errorContainerActive;
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
                private dashboardService: DashboardService,
                translation: TranslationService) {
        super(translation);
    }

    loadingDone(e): void {
        this.streamLoading = false;
        this.dashboardService.localUrlStreamConnected.next(true);
    }

    loadingError(e): void {
        this.streamLoading = false;
        this.dashboardService.localUrlStreamConnected.next(false);
        this.errorContainerActive = true;
    }

    reconnectToStream(e): void {
        this.streamLoading = true;
        this.errorContainerActive = !this.errorContainerActive;
    }

    sanitize(url: string): any {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-local-url-container">
    <loadable [loading]="streamLoading" [type]="'black-sm'">
        <div class="local-url-content" *ngIf="!errorContainerActive">
            <img id="local-url-stream"
                 class="mx-auto d-block"
                 (load)="loadingDone($event)"
                 (error)="loadingError($event)"
                 [src]="localUrl">
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-local-url-error-content" *ngIf="errorContainerActive">
            <p class="text" translate>Error connecting to stream</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reconnectToStream($event)" translate>Reconnect</button>
        </div>
    </loadable>
</div>
```

Задача следующая, в тег IMG приходит mjpeg поток, при переключении потока в firefox предыдущий поток на завершается, использовать переменную localUrl невыгодно в данном случае т.к. механизм рендеринга шаблона ангуляра не мгновенен... следственно когда компонент уничтожается, нужно подсунуть тегу img атрибуту src пустой src... Было бы круто, но просто взяв элемент через ElementRef и установив ему src через sanitize в коде компонента я получаю несколько другую ошибку...

Есть возможность установить src из кода компонента чтобы тег img мгновенно обновился в шаблоне ?

**Решение:**

Похоже конечно на костыль и скорее всего так и есть, но работает в firefox.

```
streamStop() {
    let imgElem = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#local-url-stream');
    if (imgElem) {
        imgElem.src = 'assets/images/invisible.png';
    }
}
```

Просто вызываю этот метод в местах где мне нужно завершить текущий стрим, допустим в момент ngOnDestroy...

Comment: попробуй `onError="this.src='';"` в `<img>`

Comment: За обработку ошибок тега img я использую метод в классе компонента - (error)="loadingError($event)", но мне нужно установить src во время уничтожения компонента во время ngOnDestroy при переходе пользователя на другой роут либо при закрытии компонента, не важно. Проблема в браузере firefox, если я просто уничтожу тег img(соответственно во время уничтожения компонента), браузер продолжит получать от сервера картинки для потока mjpeg, а если я во время ngOnDestroy изменю значение переменной которая в шаблоне установлена атрибуту src, шаблон обновится не мгновенно, компонент уничтожится и печаль.

Comment: кстати, а почему именно поток? У меня тоже какие-то проблемы были с этим, я решил просто `base64` передавать

Comment: Должен быть поток, т.е. обновляющиеся картинки, имитация живого видео... Решение с base64 кажется весьма адекватным. Я думаю можно реализовать сервис который будет с определенным интервалом запрашивать новую картинку, в зависимости от реализации сервера получать сразу base64 и обновлять тег img... Вы имеет в виду так ?

Comment: да, я тк и сделал примерно у себя, не помню почему, но стрим не зашел

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Comment: если сделаете с потоком, то напишите ответ плз

Comment: Это маловероятно, было попробовано многое.... но если что, отпишусь...

Comment: Добавил свое решение в текст вопроса.

Comment: Если нужно быстрое "внеплановое" обновление попробуйте воспользоваться `ChangeDetectorRef` и `markForCheck()`

Comment: Может заранее прописать img с пустым src , а потом ngswitch или ngif?

Comment: #Sharer,  я уже решил свою проблему, спасибо за желание помочь...